# Wait for signal MEX Function

Tags: c, matlab, unix, mex

I'm trying to create a MEX Function for MATLAB which will just wait for a UNIX signal.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
void sigHandler(void)
{
    sigset_t set;
    int sig;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    if(sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR2) == -1)
        perror("sigaddset error");
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);

    if(sigwait(&set, &sig) == -1)
        perror("sigwait failed\n");

    return;
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                 int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    sigHandler();
    return;
}
```

When I execute this function it's working but after sending a SIGUSR2 to MATLAB process, MATLAB is crashing.

Any idea on why?

Comment: Is your `sigHandler()` a real signal handler or is just misleadingly named? If it's a real signal handler, calling `sigwait()` and `perror()` inside it is wrong.

Comment: Yeah it's a misleading name because before that I was trying to use signal instead of sigwait but it implies to put a pause or sleep and I don't want that ...

Comment: The problem is that I'm sending my signal using a kill command to MATLAB's PID but the signal isn't forwarded to sigwait ... And I don't know how to solve this issue